# converting a numpy string array to numpy float array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I'm reading a csv file to dict. I want the key to be string, and the value to be an array of a float, like this:

```
"A":array[5.19494526e-02  1.17357977e-01  5.19494526e-02]
```

but I'm getting this:

```
"A":array['5.19494526e-02  1.17357977e-01  5.19494526e-02'].
```

trying to run this code to fix it:

```py
a=pd.read_csv('Encoded.csv', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True).to_dict()
encoded={}
for key, value in a.items():
    x = np.array(value)
    y = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float32)
    encoded[key]=y
print(encoded)
return encoded
```

but I'm getting "could not convert string to float", why?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that in the line `y = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float32)`, the variable `x` is an array of length one containing multiple space-separated substrings that can each be converted to a float. However, the string itself cannot be converted to float.

You can try replacing that line with this:

```py
y = np.asarray(x[0].split(), dtype=np.float32)
```

Input

```
{'A': array(['5.19494526e-02  1.17357977e-01  5.19494526e-02'], dtype='<U46')}
```

Output

```
{'A': array([0.05194945, 0.11735798, 0.05194945], dtype=float32)}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting "too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed"

Comment: That would seem to suggest that the value in your dict is not a numpy array but just a string. If that's true, then you can change the assignment to y to be `y = np.asarray(str(x).split(), dtype=np.float32)`. Or better yet, you can probably replace both the x assignment and the y assignment with this: `y = np.asarray(value.split(), dtype=np.float32)`.

Comment: Thanks! it works. I also needed to strip the string from the brackets :)